# Store/restore state of RecyclerView in Fragment between activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

In one of my activities I have two fragments in a `ViewPager`. Now I'm trying to save the `RecyclerView`'s state for one of them using this code:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    mListState = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    state.putParcelable("LIST_STATE_KEY", mListState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (state != null) {
        mListState = state.getParcelable("LIST_STATE_KEY");

        if (mListState != null) {
            layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work for me and I'm trying to find out how I can develop that to resolve this problem.

Comment: try this state.putParcelableArrayList("LIST_STATE_KEY", mListState); make sure mListState is type arraylist and you have also implements Parcelable on your model class

Comment: @AmeerHamza no, mListState is `Parcelable`

Comment: my bad i though you want to store data now i look your code carefully you want to store the position of list view am i right?

Comment: @AmeerHamza yes, i want to save position of recyclerview and scroll that after come back

Comment: here how i move to current location after screen rotate https://github.com/ameerhamza6733/ameerhamza6733.championtrophy2017schedule/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ameerhamza6733/championtrophy2017schedule/fragments/RecylerviewFragment.java#L140

Comment: @AmeerHamza `KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER` commented on your link as code,

Comment: bro you need study  setRecyclerViewLayoutManager function only KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER was used to check if user have linar/grid layout before rotating screen

Comment: @AmeerHamza its not clear for me, because in `onSaveInstanceState` you dont save position or state of that

Comment: i am not saving state because, when i rotate the screen onCreatView again call that why set layout manger again call i just simply checking if already layout has been set then get the the position and set to recylerview